# Docker From python:2 containarized simple code not running nohup parallel commands

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, containers, nohup

I have sample code to run some mode in python which needs to run 4000 times to complete the process. I have been created a docker build using the docker file below.

```
FROM python:2
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install fbprophet
CMD ["python", "./startup.py"]
```

Inside the startup.py file I am creating one shell script file which having 4000 nohup commands need to run as python scripts,

here is the example of sample nohup command will start at the end of "startup.py" script.

```
nohup python `runprocess.py` arg1 arg2
```

My problem is if I start the build using docker run command, let say docker build name is startup-build

```
docker run startup-build
```

This will create the shell script inside the container and start only 2 or 3 nohup commands from the file, not entire commands. ideally, it should start 100 processes at a time because the script file has 'wait' command on after every 100 lines.

I don't know why is this happening. I am running this docker image in GCP container optimized OS VM, The actual problem is the container starting while 'docker run' not using the entire resources available in the VM and not completing the process on time.

Is it because of docker image can't run shell command inside container parallel ? or does there nohup command have any limitation?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to introduce shell scripting in your Python stack, as you obviously want to use the Python based fbprophet module (you also seem to suggest that you want to run your shell commands (nohup...) in a Python script). You might as well use the Python subprocess module to run and control your subprocesses. Then you could also limit your running processes to a specific number by running them in a loop.

Comment: @ofrommel My use case is to run 4000 processes in that 100 will start parallel that's why I am using nohup. the question specifically does docker container support 100 parallel nohup processes or not?

Comment: How do you know that the nohup commands have not been started and already completed?

Comment: one way is using docker stats command to check the status of the container. another way is to check the processes running in the machine 'ps -ef | grep text nohup or python'

Comment: @sxm1972 actually the nohup is starting. I didn't say it is not starting. But the issues are, it is not starting the 100 processes parallel. The container starting only a few of the nohup commands let say 3 or 4. And the specific container not using the given resources. Even if I limit it.. like "docker run --cpus=64 --memory=50g --memory-swap=56g image-name"